# Applying regex in bash

Tags: regex, bash

I'm trying to get my filename without its extension using a regex I found on Stack Overflow. The regex is:

```
(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)
```

I try this on the command line

```
echo TestFileName.1.0.0.2.zip | grep "(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)"
```

And I get nothing in the command line.  If I try it with this regex:

```
echo TestFileName.1.0.0.2.zip | grep "Test"
```

I do see the TestFileName.1.0.0.2.zip gets printed to the console with Test highlighted in red.  When I tried my data in this website: http://rubular.com/r/LNrI4inMU1

It does seem to work.  Am I applying the regex wrong in Bash?

Comment: your regex in the rubular link is wrong..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're using an extended regular expression; the standard regex language which grep uses doesn't support what you're trying to do.  Change grep to be `grep -E` and the match will work.  This specifies that your regex is an extended one.

```
$ echo TestFileName.1.0.0.2.zip | grep -E "(.+?)(\.[^.]*$|$)"
TestFileName.1.0.0.2.zip
```

See [this link](http://www.regular-expressions.info/posix.html) for more information on the distinction between regular and extended regex.

Answer (score 1):

Using BASH regex:

```
s='TestFileName.1.0.0.2.zip'
[[ "$s" =~ ^(.*)\.[^.]+$ ]] && echo "${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"
TestFileName.1.0.0.2
```

Answer (score 0):

Add `-P` (*Perl-regexp*) parameter to your grep along with `-o` (*only-matching*).

```
$ echo TestFileName.1.0.0.2.zip | grep -oP "(.+)(?=\.)"
TestFileName.1.0.0.2
```